# Facebook Graph Api publish photo to fan page album and tag author on it

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, tags, facebook-page, facebook-tag

We are a French Mobile Agengy working on a touchy Facebook integration (Graph API and mobile SDK). 
That application (iOS & Android) consist in a picture contest, where the winner is the one who gets the more likes on its picture published on the Facebook Fan Page.

1. Each user connect via Facebook Connect.
2. They can take a picture with their phone and upload it to our server for moderation.
3. When the picture is validated by our review team we want to do the following interactions with Facebook :

3-1. Publish the picture to a specific album of a fan page (this part is working well, doing validation with a Facebook connected user, being admin of the fan page and granting "manage_pages" to the fbapp of this operation)

3-2. Then we want to "tag" the author on the photo - author being the facebook user which uploaded the photo to our server -, so that the picture shows off on this user timeline - not a post referencing the picture, because the "likes" must be on the picture and not on a share of it.

We are stuck on the 3-2 step, since we could not find a way to properly tag a user on a fan page picture using Graph API (either as a user or a page or an app - access_tokens).

In a more functional point of view, we want to post a picture in a Facebook Fan Page Album (via a fbapp), and have this picture integrated on both Fan Page and User (Author) timelines without having to repost this picture (to prevent likes fragmentation between picture and shares).

Hope my explanations are clear, any help will be (greatly) welcome. :)

Comment: Watch it : "Some code"